# Numerical operations on 2D array in python using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the below array. How can I apply numerical operation to each x,y as
x*3+1,(y+2)*2 using numpy.

A = [[2,4],[1,5],[6,3],[],[],[],[].....[x,y]]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: ;) indeed a working solution should be the first guess one tries. Numpy thinks like a human :)

Comment: just make sure your object is a numpy-array. What you wrote in the question is a list of lists. `numpy.array(A)` would give an array.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious list approach:

```
In [111]: A = [[2,4],[1,5],[6,3]]
In [112]: def foo(x,y):
     ...:     return x*3+1,(y+2)*2 
     ...: 
In [113]: [foo(x,y) for x,y in A]
Out[113]: [(7, 12), (4, 14), (19, 10)]
```

Make an array, and pass columns to the function:

```
In [114]: AA = np.array(A)
In [115]: AA
Out[115]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [6, 3]])
In [116]: foo(AA[:,0], AA[:,1])
Out[116]: (array([ 7,  4, 19]), array([12, 14, 10]))
```

The result is a tuple of arrays; transpose can turn that into an array:

```
In [117]: np.transpose(_)
Out[117]: 
array([[ 7, 12],
       [ 4, 14],
       [19, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using a simple nested for loop, but first just make sure it is a numpy array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8],[10,11]])

rows = a.shape[0]
cols = a.shape[1]

for x in range(0, rows):
    for y in range(0, cols, 2): # the last param 2 is the incremented by number
        #do you operation here
        print (a[x,y])
        print (a[x,y+1])
        print (a[x,y]*3+1,(a[x,y+1]+2)*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
#Convert normal array to np array
A = np.array([[2,4],[1,5],[6,3]])
print A
B = np.array([A[:,0]*3 + np.ones(A.shape[0]), (A[:,1] + np.ones(A.shape[0])*2)*2], float).T
print B #This is the array with operations done on it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forwardly:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,4],[1,5],[6,3]])
a[:,0] = a[:,0]*3+1
a[:,1] = (a[:,-1]+2)*2

print(a)
```

The output:

```
[[ 7 12]
 [ 4 14]
 [19 10]]
```